# Pandas distorting html tables

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I extracted some tables from a html file using Pandas and BeautifulSoup. However, the output is really messy. For some reason, Pandas adds columns and makes the Original columns unaligned. The header and rest of the columns are not in the same column anymore. Similarly, it cuts off columns when ) or % are in the column.

This is the code I used to extract the table I want:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1961/0001264931-18-000031.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    if (('income tax' in str(table)) or ('Income tax' in str(table))) and (('Statutory' in str(table)) or ('statutory' in str(table))):
            df = pd.read_html(str(table))
            print(df[0])
    else:
        pass
```

Not sure why df[0] prints the whole list, but that is no problem for me. The table I am intersted in looks like:

```py
[                                                   0   1       2    3     4  \
0                                                NaN NaN  2017.0  NaN  2016   
1  Income tax computed at the federal statutory rate NaN     NaN   34     %   
2    Income tax computed at the state statutory rate NaN     NaN    5     %   
3                                Valuation allowance NaN     NaN  (39    )%   
4                           Total deferred tax asset NaN     NaN    0     %   

    5   6    7    8  
0 NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  
1 NaN NaN   34    %  
2 NaN NaN    5    %  
3 NaN NaN  (39   )%  
4 NaN NaN    0    %  ]
```

If I display the html code this table is based on, it looks clean with columns aligned. However, using Pandas it is messy. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: it's not distorted, that's the table in it's raw form. The reason it looks "clean" in html is because it's rendered by an application that understands html and the tags associated with it's formatting. Secondly, there are 731 `<table>` tags. Based on your `if` statement, 6 of those tags return as `True`, hence it prints those out as well.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Any tips on how to get this to the 'clean' version so I can process it further?

Comment: store as a pandas dataframe and then manipulate through pandas